# How to get the xml node value into a string

Tags: c#, xml

How to get the xml node value in a string.

i am getting This error

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

error shown in this line

```
xmldoc.LoadXml(xmlFile);
```

my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<UOM>

  <!-- The selected currency used will be stored here for Code reference" -->
  <ActiveCurrencyType>
    <ActiveCurrency>U.S.Dollar</ActiveCurrency>
    <ActiveCode>USD</ActiveCode>
    <ActiveSymbol>$</ActiveSymbol>
  </ActiveCurrencyType>

  <!-- The selected Dimension used will be stored here for Code reference -->
  <ActiveDimension>
    <ActiveDimensionUOM>Inches</ActiveDimensionUOM>
    <ActiveDimensionSymbol>.in</ActiveDimensionSymbol>
  </ActiveDimension>

  <!-- The selected weight used will be stored here for Code reference -->
  <ActiveWeight>
    <ActiveWeightUOM>Pounds</ActiveWeightUOM>
    <ActiveWeightSymbol>lb</ActiveWeightSymbol>
  </ActiveWeight>

</UOM>
```

C# code

```
    string xmlFile = Server.MapPath("~/HCConfig/HCUOM.xml");
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.LoadXml(xmlFile);
    XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("ActiveDimensionSymbol");
    string ActiveDimensionSymbol = string.Empty;
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
    {
        ActiveDimensionSymbol = node.InnerText;
    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I've just tested your code and it loads the file just fine. Check, that your path is correct. (`Server.MapPath()`)

Comment: Think your XML file path is not correct. Your code is just fine. alternatively you could try XDocument. XDocument doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
            var symbols = doc.Root.Descendants("ActiveDimension").Select(x => x.Elements("ActiveDimensionSymbol").ToList()).ToList();

Comment: @kashi_rock no, if that would have been the case a different exception would have been thrown., Do note the Op using the `XmlDocument` class, not `XDocument`

Comment: I was able to reproduce this error while using XmlDocument but was able to read the XML using XDocument. Even I got the same error with my valid XML files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong overload, `LoadXml` doesn't do what you think it does.

Use [`xmldoc.Load(xmFile);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807(v=vs.110).aspx) because that method takes an file path as input. `LoadXml` expects an string with xml in it.

The exception is an indicator of that mistake. What is processed is not XML, and a filepath isn't that.

After this changes the string `ActiveDimensionSymbol` contains `.in` if I run this locally.

If you want to use [`LoadXml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v=vs.110).aspx) you should first read your whole file in a string, for example like so:

```
 xmldoc.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText(xmlFile));
```

but is really only overhead to call [`File.ReadAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=vs.110).aspx) if there is an method that accepts a file.

Comment: I think problem is not there, I have tried everything locally but same result, and use XDocuments instead and works just fine

Comment: @Mostafiz I did the same and replacing that single method call makes the code work, it even returns the expected outcome

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Descendants()` method to get all XElements by certain name, found in the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
string[] allActiveWeightUOMs = doc.Descendants("ActiveWeightUOM").Select(o => o.Value).ToArray();

// allActiveWeightUOMs : "Pounds" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As can seen here [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) the method that you are using to load the XML excepts xml by string not xml file. You can use `XmlDocument.Load` instead of `XmlDocument.LoadXml`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code its works just fine with this xml

```
string xmlFile = Server.MapPath("~/HCConfig/HCUOM.xml");
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile );

var nodeList = doc.Descendants("ActiveDimensionSymbol");
string ActiveDimensionSymbol = string.Empty;
foreach (var node in nodeList)
{
   ActiveDimensionSymbol = node.Value;
}
```